# Copying log files in heavy use are sometimes empty until opened in windows

Tags: c#, file, io

Copying log files on a slow VM with heavy usage occasionally results in an empty file and no error is raised even though file is known not to be empty.

I have seen file show zero bytes and the copy is zero bytes but when original file is opened in Notepad windows shows the correct size and Notepad shows all the log lines expected.

```
var files = info.GetFiles(dir).OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime);
foreach (IFileInfo file in files)
{
    if ((file.CreationTime >= from && file.CreationTime <= to) || (file.LastWriteTime >= from && file.LastWriteTime <= to))
    {
        if (file.Extension.Equals(".log", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
            file.Extension.Equals(".txt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            _fileWriter(file, outputFilePath);
        }

    }
}
```

This logging system is known to result in Windows file tunneling effect if that is of interest.

Adding FileInfo.Refresh() to this function will that fix the issue? It is hard to test as it happens very infrequently.

Comment: How do you know the log files weren't empty when you tried to copy them?

Comment: Because each log line has a date, and the date can be hours ago. The logging that is being done has no caching mechanism but writes it to disk continuously